# about ubuntu software centre

Tags: 12.04

I've installed ubuntu 12.04 using windows ubuntu installer.I am trying to get softwares from ubuntu software centre but it is giving option 'more info' and not being installed.
What to do in this case?

Comment: Do you see install after clicking the 'more info'? If not, can you give a screenshot of what you see after clicking 'more info'?

Answer (score 1):

Click on the **More info** button, and then you will see the package description, a screenshot of the application if there is one available and an **Install** button located on the right-hand side of the window.

Answer (score 0):

You should click on any application or software you need to install. It will open a new window, and on top-right side you will be able to see whether it is free/commercial version and also an Install button with it.